# SQL 2005 query all databases and output to one table

Tags: sql-server-2005

Need a little help with the below:

I've created a query which basically will give me all the stored procedures in all the table for every database and I want to try and amend it so that the output queries are output to one table.

Any suggestions on how to improve this?

```
DECLARE @command varchar(1000) 
SELECT @command = 

'USE [?] select *,  DB_NAME() as DatabaseName  
from sys.all_objects where type=''p'' and is_ms_shipped=0 '

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select  *,DB_NAME() as DB_NAME
into    mytable
from    sys.all_objects
where   1=2
```

---

```
DECLARE @command varchar(1000) 
SELECT @command = 

'USE [?] select *,  DB_NAME() as DatabaseName  
from sys.all_objects where type=''p'' and is_ms_shipped=0 '

insert into mytable  EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
```

---

Using table variable

```
declare  @mytable table (
    [name] [sysname] NOT NULL,
    [object_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [principal_id] [int] NULL,
    [schema_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [parent_object_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [type] [char](2) NULL,
    [type_desc] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    [create_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [modify_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [is_ms_shipped] [bit] NULL,
    [is_published] [bit] NULL,
    [is_schema_published] [bit] NULL,
    [DB_NAME] [nvarchar](128) NULL
    )


DECLARE @command varchar(1000) 
SELECT @command = 

'USE [?] select *,  DB_NAME() as DatabaseName  
from sys.all_objects where type=''p'' and is_ms_shipped=0 '

insert into @mytable  EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command 

select * from @mytable
```

Comment: I can't create a new table it needs to be in the results only.

Comment: temp table?......

Comment: Make it a temptable or a table variable.

Comment: Add `#` before the name of the table

Comment: any other way to merge the results as opposed to moving them into a table? My manager is likely to disapprove of this :(

Comment: See updated answer (table variable)

Comment: Be aware that `sp_MSforeachdb` has potential problems.  Please see Aaron's excellent article about how to replace it with a great alternative option:  https://sqlblog.org/2020/08/04/reliable-flexible-replacement-sp_msforeachdb

Answer (score 1):

Without cursor and undocumented sp_MSforeachdb, below is how you can do

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO
--drop table #results;
CREATE TABLE #results
(
  DatabaseName SYSNAME,
  SchemaName SYSNAME,
  StoredProcedureName SYSNAME, 
  create_date datetime,
  modify_date datetime
);
GO

declare @sqltext nvarchar(max) = N''
declare @dbname sysname

-- build dynamic sql for all online databases !
select @sqltext += @sqltext+N' insert into #results select  db_name() as DatabaseName, SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) as SchemaName,
 [name] as StoredProcedureName , create_date, modify_date 
FROM '+QUOTENAME(name)+'.sys.procedures where is_ms_shipped = 0
order by [object_id];'
  FROM sys.databases 
  WHERE database_id > 4 AND [state] = 0 AND user_access = 0 AND is_read_only = 0;

exec sp_executesql @sqltext

select * from #results
drop table #results;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create temporary table and store the result inside.

```
DECLARE @command varchar(1000) 
SELECT @command = 

'USE [?] SELECT *,  DB_NAME() AS DatabaseName  
FROM sys.all_objects WHERE type=''p'' AND is_ms_shipped=0'

SELECT TOP 0 *,  DB_NAME() AS DatabaseName INTO #Result
FROM sys.all_objects

INSERT INTO #Result
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command

SELECT * FROM #Result

DROP TABLE #Result
```

But you should really care about undocumented sp_MSforeachdb. There is a lot of the limitations here.